# Ruby Net::HTTP and iframe src

Tags: html, ruby

Currently I'm learning how to get html page, and I have interesting question. For example, I have something like `iframe` on my page and I want to get all data for single `Net::HTTP.get` request.

For example, loaded page looks like that:

```
<body>
  <h1>My page</h1>
  <iframe src='some_url'>
    <html>
      <head>
        ...
      </head>
    <html>
  </iframe>
</body>
```

But if I will do `Net::HTTP` request I will get only

```
<body>
  <h1>My page</h1>
  <iframe src='some_url'></iframe>
</body>
```

Is there a way to get all page with a sing `Net::HTTP` request?

Comment: No, there isn't. The `src` points to a different resource, so you must make a request for that resource. Your browser does the same thing.

Comment: Jordan above is right, I just wanted to add that what you're seeing is a behavior of your browser interpreting HTML (a document framework), not of HTTP (a communications protocol). You'll need a library that understands HTML (like Nokogiri) to be able to interact with the document more like a browser would.

Comment: I want to be more detailed, I have `frameset` on a page, what have two frames. Right now I'm unable to do Net::HTTP request, and I want to make it load some how. How can nokogiri help me with that?

Comment: You would use Nokogiri to parse the HTML on the page, find the framesets, then run your Net::HTTP requests (or maybe recursively use Nokogiri, up to you).